# Rails initialize new object with defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following class:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :choices
end
```

I want to initialize new objects to have 4 blank strings in an array, so `choices = ['','','','']`.  I've tried doing it in the controller:

```
def new
  @question = Question.new(:choices => ['','','',''])
end
```

That works, but it seems like this should be done in the model to promote data integrity.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several solutions. In order of preference

1. **Create a custom method and use it whenever you need such feature**

   ```
   class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :choices

     def self.prepare
       new(:choices => ['','','',''])
     end
   end
   ```
2. **Use the `after_initialize` callback**

   ```
   class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :choices

     after_initialize :default_choices

     protected

     def :default_choices
       self.choices ||= ['','','','']
     end
   end
   ```
3. **Override `choices`**

I encourage the first approach for several reasons

1. You will have more control of the code. The defaults will be assigned only when you explicitly want it. In fact, there are several cases where an instance of that record is initialized (think about tests) and the majority of time that assignment may not be required
2. It's a good step towards exposing a custom API that is not tightly coupled to ActiveRecord
3. It exposes a more maintainable approach
4. You will love it if your app complexity will increase

Comment: So you then would just call question.prepare from the controller?  That currently would only happen after new and create, but it could happen in other places at some point.

Comment: Yes. There is nothing bad about calling a custom method in the controller. Actually, this is a good idea to expose a custom model API in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

4 **Set as default in migration**

```rb
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :questions do |t|
     t.string :choices, default: ['', '', '', '']
     t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```

but I agree the first is the best solution.

In any case do not override the initialize http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html, use the **`after_initialize`** callback described in the second solution.